# App works on emulator but not on real device

Tags: java, android

I have a music player app that I'm developing just to learn, and I wanted to test it on my phone. If I run the app on the emulator it works like a charm, but if I use my real phone for debugging then it stops at this part:

```
loadFiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/");

public void loadFiles(String path) {
    Log.d(TAG, "loadFiles");
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] files = f.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {
         ... //Wont run
    }
}
```

So I added another `Log.d` before the if to see what's wrong and turns out that the `files` is null. No errors, and works in the emulator.

App written in API 21, the phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro, android 10, I have USB debugging enabled.

Log after run (Errors, full log [here](https://pastebin.com/9qeTCiLJ)):

```
2021-05-20 20:40:51.713 20237-20237/? I/rox.musicplaye: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-05-20 20:40:51.738 20237-20237/? E/rox.musicplaye: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-05-20 20:40:52.059 20237-20237/com.wotrox.musicplayer I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2021-05-20 20:40:52.074 20237-20237/com.wotrox.musicplayer I/FeatureParser: can't find lavender.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
2021-05-20 20:40:52.088 20237-20237/com.wotrox.musicplayer E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
2021-05-20 20:40:52.078 20237-20237/com.wotrox.musicplayer W/rox.musicplayer: type=1400 audit(0.0:54557): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=13065 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c155,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_displayfeature_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2021-05-20 20:40:52.094 20237-20268/com.wotrox.musicplayer E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.wotrox.musicplayer
2021-05-20 20:40:52.095 20237-20268/com.wotrox.musicplayer E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2021-05-20 20:40:52.096 20237-20268/com.wotrox.musicplayer E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.wotrox.musicplayer
2021-05-20 20:40:52.096 20237-20268/com.wotrox.musicplayer E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

Since Android 10 you have to write

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

into the Manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `multidexEnabled` in your `build.gradle`:

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```

clean , build and run

If that does not work try to enable USB Debugging Mode. [Here's](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm) a manual

you might be missing some SDK's, but this is unlikely.

Comment: Does the same thing

Comment: Can you show us the logs you are getting from the app?

Comment: I added the logs after the second run because the first always throw a load of errors, but I  don't think this matters

Comment: Based on your logs, it has something to do with your phone permissions, have you enabled usb debugging on your phone?